# How dynamically dropdown list values changes by selecting another dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have two dropdown lists. One is weekday, another is type of food.
In page load i am getting weekdays values list in weekday dropdown list.

Now the problem is by selecting values in weekday dropdown, the corresponding values have for food have to be fetched from the database.

example: Suppose if I select monday in weekday dropdown list, the second dropdown needs to  display what are the items present in the monday day .

datatabase is already designed.

Answer (score 4):

In selection change event of the first drop down, get the details of the second drop down from the database and bind it. To fire the selection changed event whenever user selects a new item, set `AutoPostback=true` for the drop down list.

If you want to use Ajax; you can take a look at the [Cascading Drop Down Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Here you should not set the `AutoPostback=true` as the extender will take care of it.

Comment: Make sure you set autopostback=true for the first drop down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selection change event of your weekday combobox. Inside that event fetch the data according to current selected item and then set the result to the food combobox.

List outputfoodList;

//Retrive foods and assing result to list
...
...
...

for(string food in outputfoodList)
{
`foodCmb.Items.Add(food);`
}